# HereMap ios premum sdk showInfoBubble

Tags: ios, marker, here-api

I am working with Here maps ios [premium](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics/maps.html) SDK. I want to show info bubble on `NMAMapMarker` I can't find showInfoBubble() method on premium SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The `InfoBubble` as you know it from the JS API is not supported in that way. Within the SDK you have the possibility to choose own images:

The `NMAMapMarker` class is used to display a custom icon at a fixed geographical position on the map.
Custom icons can be one of the following file formats:

- BMP
- SVG
- JPEG
- PNG

Please see the `NMAImage` API Reference for more information on working with these file formats.